# Modify datapoints value in cloudwatch alarm with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

The number of datapoints that must be breaching to trigger the alarm can be configured and its documented in the [PutMetricAlarm API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricAlarm.html) reference but it's missing from the [CloudFormation docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cw-alarm.html).

I tried to do it in Java with Cloudformation but it returns an error that property is unknown.

Is there any was to change the datapoints value with cloudformation ?

Comment: this is not currently supported by Cloudformation, are you trying to use lambda for calling the api with java?